# Spring integration annotation Java 8 Optional Incorrect Handling

Tags: java, spring, java-8, spring-boot, spring-integration

I am using Spring boot 1.2.2.Release and Java 8, the problem is that Spring is wrapping `Optional payload` into new Optional objects as many times as I am passing it through `transformer/service activator`. E.g.

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = ..., outputChannel = ...) 
public Optional<Foo> transform() {returns -> Optional.of(foo);}

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = ..., outputChannel = ...)
public Optional<Foo> doSomething1(Optional<Foo> payload) {
     payload.ifPresent(f -> {System.out.println(f.getId());}); // this line throws ClassCastException 
  return foo;
}
```

The reason why above code throws ClassCastExcpetion(cannot cast java.util.Optional to Foo) because `payload` instead of containing `foo` as value contains another Optional Object and that Optional object contains `foo` as value.

I have read [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#4.1-Optional-Parameter) where it mentioned

> Now Spring Integration consistently handles the Java 8's Optional
>   type.

I even tried with exact version of the framework mentioned in the document but no success

**Workaround** : I tried to create some Wrapper(PayloadWrapper) object that contains payload and it works. But may be there is some other way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the documentation is not clear. The problem is that spring can transform **method parameters** into `Optional<Type>`, but in this case, you parameter is already an `Optional`, so Spring wraps it again..

If you make your transform method just return `Foo` (with no `Optional`), then Spring will wrap a Foo instance (or 'null') in an `Optional` when it's passed to the `ServiceActivator`

Comment: This is good answer as a workaround, Thanks. But anyway there is a bug which is out of the Spring Integration scope: The `ObjectToOptionalConverter`, which does not take care about the source `Optional<?>` type: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12785

Comment: @ArtemBilan Thanks for creating the issue, now its status is resolved, just waiting for new release to happen.